# Mongodb $Multiply returns null value

Tags: json, mongodb, aggregate

I am new to mongo, and I want to get the total amount of an order,
I am using decimal for price and int for quantity, it returns null all the time, can you please help me out with this 
thank in advance

```
db.order.aggregate([
{
 $project:{
        total:{
            $multiply:['$qty','$price'] // this returns null, price in decimal, and qty is int
                }}}])
```

Comment: Can you show the document for which it returns `null`?

Comment: {
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "date" : "2020-05-10",
    "book" : [ 
        {
            "price" : NumberDecimal("10.0"),
            "ISBN" : "a1",
            "qty" : 10
        }, 
        {
            "price" : NumberDecimal("100.0"),
            "ISBN" : "a2",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}

Comment: ```db.order.aggregate([
{
 $project:{
        total:{
            book:{
            $multiply:['$qty','$price'] // this returns null, price in decimal, and qty is int
            }
            }}}])```

Answer (score 1):

Since `book` is an array you need to use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) in order to run `$multiply` for each element. You can also use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) and [$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/index.html) to keep input data:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
            book: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$book",
                    in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                            "$$this",
                            { total: { $multiply: [ "$$this.qty", "$$this.price" ] } }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4ybSBkNwY7J)